# Adsense misleading rejection: Valuable Inventory: No content

Tags: google-adsense

I have a blog that has around 30 posts and over 5K hits per month. 
Trying to get approved with adsense, I keep getting "No Content". How can I debug the cause of this?

Other questions about this received an answer about an HTTP canonical URL, which is not the case here, as it's https only.

The blog is: https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 pages isn't enough to get approved for AdSense.  To get approved for AdSense you need:

- 50 pages of original content
- A clean design

  - make it clear what the site is about
  - make sure the content on each page is front and center
  - include obvious navigation to the various pages (Reviewers may fail the review after viewing just the home page unless they see navigation to 50 pages from the home page)
- Plenty of text (Several hundred words per page minimum is recommended)
- A contact page
- An about us page
- A privacy policy
- Have owned and operated your site for a year

Make sure you submit your canonical URL.  I've seen AdSense reviews rejected for no content because `http://example.com/` was submitted when the site actually uses HTTPS.   The same goes for www vs no-www.

5K hits per month isn't enough to make any money with AdSense.  At most you could make a few dollars per month.  It could take you many months or years to reach the $100 payment threshold.  So don't sweat not getting approved right away, you aren't missing much.   Grow your site more first.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, any references as to how you know this?

Comment: Google's official stance is that there is no "set minimum" policy.  However, people in various forums have had problems getting in with fewer than 50 pages.    This is advice I have given in the past: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121933/how-long-should-i-expect-it-to-take-to-get-ads-on-a-web-site/121940#121940

Comment: I've been an AdSense publisher myself for years, so I have experience with the revenue per thousand page views (RPM): it will typically be up to $2 per thousand visitors (but has the potential to be much lower than that depending on the type of visitor, the site niche, and the amount of ad optimization you've done.)